# Compute Forward Variance Swap

Tags: delta-hedging

I'm trying to compute a forward variance like this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.04073.pdf.

The paper shows that under rough stochastic volatility model assumption, options can be hedged with the underlying and variance swap.

I'm particularly interested in etablished a baseline for my work by replicating the experiment hedging VIX option which is modeled by

$$VIX_t = C e^{X_t}, \quad X_t = \sigma W^H_t,$$
where $W^H$ is a fractional Brownian motion.

I can follow the paper to the part of getting delta hedge which is

- $dP_t = N(d_t^1) dVIX_t$.
- $dP_t = \frac{N(d^1_t)e^{-\frac{1}{2}}(c^T(T) - c^T(t))}{2\sqrt{F^T_t}}dF_t^T$.

Here, $F^t$ is the forward variance ($F^T_t = \mathbb{E}_Q[VIX^2_T|\mathcal{F}_t]$).

To perform back test, the paper mentioned that the back test uses **synthetic forward variance curve data**, computed from S&P index options.

I wonder how the forward variance is computed here? Can I compute it using realized variance swap.

Additional questions after editting:

> The initial value of the hedging portfolio is initialized with the ATM VIX
> option price with maturity 1.5 months computed within the model

Does this mean that the strike $K$ is set to $S_0$?

> the
> quantity of the hedging asset in the portfolio is initialized with the corresponding model-based hedge ratio.

Does "model-based hedge ration" mean the delta hedge in the above formula?

(I'm from ML background, so I may not know many basic concepts in finance)

Comment: Pls add details to your question so that it can still be understood and answered even if the link you have provided gets broken or changed.

Comment: I have clarified further. Hope the question is in a better form now.